# How to execute a conditional grep based on a shell function argument?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, pipe

I have the following function:

```
function long_command() {
     cat $1 | grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5}' | \
     cat -n | sed -e 's/    / /g' | \
     sed -e 's/^  *//g' | \
     sort -k 3,3 -k 1n,1n | \
     uniq -f 2 | \
     sed -e 's/^[0-9]\{1,\} //' | \
     grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+' | \
     cat -n
}
```

The first part of the command filters some stuff. In the last part of the command I would like to filter using `grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+'` **only if the argument** `$2` is set and equals let's say `VALUE`, before piping to the last `cat -n`. How can I do that?

This doesn't work:

```
function long_command() {
     cat $1 | grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5}' | \
     cat -n | sed -e 's/    / /g' | \
     sed -e 's/^  *//g' | \
     sort -k 3,3 -k 1n,1n | \
     uniq -f 2 | \
     sed -e 's/^[0-9]\{1,\} //' | \
     if [ "$2" -eq "VALUE" ];  then grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+'; fi | \
     cat -n
}
```

I get an error:

```
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

What't the correct way to use an if and pipe the result of the if to `cat -n`?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You need to learn how to use command line utilities efficiently. That pipe can be simplified to one or two commands. If you would add some relevant input data and the expected output I could show how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `if/else` like shown in pipeline command since there is nothing in the `else` part. Also `-eq` requires integer comparison.

You can do it like this:

```
long_command() {
     grep -vE '[a-fA-F0-9]{5}' "$1" |
     cat -n |
     sed 's/    / /g' |
     sed 's/^  *//g' |
     sort -k 3,3 -k 1n,1n |
     uniq -f 2 |
     sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,\} //' |
     { [[ $2 == "VALUE" ]] && grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+' || cat; } | cat -n
}
```

I've removed a redundant `cat` at the start and there is no need to use `\` after `|` to enter next command on new line.

After last pipe you can also use:

```
if [[ "$2" == "VALUE" ]]; then grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+'; else cat; fi
```

Comment: `You cannot use if/else in pipeline command`, You can. Just you need to make sure that in both if and else sides, the data flows through correctly. In this case, it will be `if [[ "$2" == "VALUE" ]];  then grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+'; else cat; fi`

Comment: Imo this answer is a help for commiting command-line-suicide. It should not have been answered like this. The real problem is the complexity of the pipe. The pipe needs to get cleaned up but the questions is missing relevant input data to do that.

Comment: Your point of simplifying the pipeline is valid but I think OP wants to know about using if/else/fi construct after a pipe.

Comment: @anishsane Thanks your `if [[ "$2" == "VALUE" ]]; then grep -Ev '^\s*PATTERN\s+'; else cat; fi` was what I was looking for.

Comment: @anubhava Ok, but thanks goes also to `@anishsane`, cause he pointed that out.

Comment: Absolutely, I have already expressed my gratitude to him in my earlier comment.